# C# Calculate the image scroll with scrollbar

Tags: c#, .net, scrollbar

I'm working a 2d tile-editor, used Winforms and XNA(for the map rendering) and i have a problem with the custom scrollbar.

I would like to know the formula for calculating the map scrolling depending the position value of my scrollbar.

Let me explain
Actually, i have a functional code but is not exact. 
Here is my calculation (is the problem):

(Point Map.PixelMapSize = map size in pixel)

```
    hScrollBarMap.Minimum = 0;
    hScrollBarMap.Maximum = 100;
    hScrollBarMap.LargeChange = hScrollBarMap.Size.Width * 100 /(Map.PixelMapSize.X);

    mapScrollCalcul = ((hScrollBarMap.Value - hScrollBarMap.Minimum) * 100 / (hScrollBarMap.Maximum - hScrollBarMap.Minimum)) * Map.PixelMapSize.X / 100;
```

Sorry, I do not know how to explain. I found it by making a lot of tests...
But, the mapScrollCalcul is the final calcul to be applied to map position display.

What is the exact calculation for this ?

I hope you understand, I'm not speak English, just little understand. 
But I understand you. :) (programmation language is universal)

Thank you for reading and, maybe, future responses.

Comment: What control are you scrolling?  I always found it easiest to avoid the whole matter of caluclating relative positions by using the old trick: place a PictureBox with autosize=true (or a Panel with the full size of the bitmap) inside a panel with autoscroll=true. This way you always can work with the mouse coordinates directly, without calculating offsets and without using any external scrollbars..

Comment: My control scrolling is a XNA view embedded in my winforms.
Autoscroll use is impossible because the size of the xna view is fixed. I use camera transformation (in spriteBatch.Begin) for display my map.

Comment: Off course, I can enlarge the xna view but this is not serious (and if the map is big, xna does not support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things.

First, you are setting your `LargeChange` value relative to your image, not your view, and your `scroll.Maximum` relative to... what, exactly?

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar(v=vs.110).aspx), they say:

> User interface guidelines suggest that the SmallChange and LargeChange
>   properties are set relative to the size of the view that the user
>   sees, not to the total size including the unseen part. For example, if
>   you have a picture box with scroll bars displaying a large image, the
>   SmallChange and LargeChange properties should be set relative to the
>   size of the picture box, not to the size of the image.

Now, lets assume that your image is 1000x1000 and your view is 100x100, and you are scrolling vertically. Then:

```
myVscroll.Minimum=0;
myVscroll.Maximum=image.Height; //1000
myVscroll.SmallChange = 10; // here: view.Height/10 or other value that makes scrolling look smooth
myVscroll.LargeChange = 100; // in this example, this is set to view.Height
```

And finally:

```
mapScrollCalcul = myVscroll.Value;
```

Comment: Thank you Arie, your solution works perfectly. 
I made a bad use of scrollbar. Now I know.
Thank you !